# TypeError Cannot read property `style` of undefined for nativebase

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I am using `nativebase` for a react project. But for some reason, I am getting

> Cannot read property `style` of undefined

error. I have followed all the steps mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html) for the setup.

I have also followed [`kitchensink` web version](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink/tree/web-support), which seems to be outdated and doesn't run.

There is also a similar issue raised before in GitHub which was in [2017](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/846)

#### Steps to reproduce

All the code uploaded to github. [Repo Link](https://github.com/ajitdas123/react-native-web)

#### Error Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue. Looks like native-base as of now doesn't work with react-native-web

Comment: This might not be an answer to the question. You might consider putting this as a comment instead when you have sufficient reputation.